# WCF - Implementing a ServiceHostFactory to use into IIS context (svc file)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, svc

I've successfully implemented a self-hosted WCF service. For legacy matters, the host binding configuration is read from a non-standard source (instead of app.config). When porting this service to IIS, I run into the problem of loading the settings and I found that the solution would involve implementing a class inherited from `ServiceHostFactory`.

My problem, though, is that the `CreateServiceHost` method only receives the concrete type and the URI from the SVC file, but I wanted to re-use this class to further implementations and need more information: like the interface that defines the `ServiceContract` and the binding already configured.

I found [this excellent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx) from @carlosfigueira, but its implementation uses the factory to return a host that is specific to the service, in a 1-to-1 relation. I sure can do it, but that will lead to several specific factories, with lots of copy-and-paste code and I'd ratter avoid it. Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Your service factory when it gets the concrete service should be able to resolve that information, no?

Comment: Since the `ServiceContract` attribute is not inheritable, I suppose I have to pass the interface that declares it (instead of the concrete class), when executing `AddServiceEndpoint` method. Besides that, I need another parameter to load the correct binding settings. I wonder if I can pass further parameters to the ServiceHostFactory...

Comment: Edit question with a bit more information about what you are trying to accomplish, i'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly you want. I use a single custom factory and it passes in the concrete class, but the configuration is done in web.config.

Comment: Hi, @DarrenKopp, unfortunately I can't use `web.config` and need to load the service configuration/binding from a non-standard source. The `ServiceHostFactory` is called by .SVC only with the concrete implementation `Type` instance and URI baseAdresses, though. Hence, how can I discover the ServiceContract(s) that is(are) implemented by this concrete class? Moreover, I need a key to load the right configuration settings, and it can't be inspected from meta-information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way of finding out which contracts are implemented by a service class, but the code shouldn't be too hard. It's something along the lines of the function below. You'll need some logic to determine the relative address if you have multiple contract types (i.e., if you have a single contract, use "", if you have multiple, use the contract name as the address).

```
private IEnumerable<Type> GetContractType(Type serviceType) 
{ 
    if (HasServiceContract(serviceType))
    { 
        yield return serviceType; 
    } 

    var contractInterfaceTypes = serviceType.GetInterfaces() 
        .Where(i => HasServiceContract(i));

    foreach (var type in contractInterfaceTypes)
    {
        yield return type;
    }

    // if you want, you can also go to the service base class,
    // interface inheritance, etc.
} 

private static bool HasServiceContract(Type type) 
{ 
    return Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), false); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, @carlosfigueira, thank you for your suggestion. I've already suspected I needed to dwelve into Reflection to recursively get the base classes and implemented interfaces (I already do something alike  to export the service known types), but I'd rather avoid it, because it makes code harder to read. Guess I'm going to stick with the simpler solution to create a factory specific to each SVC file, so I know beforehand which key should I use to load settings and which ServiceContract is implemented. Sometimes I get very disappointed with WCF...